# Route hooks are not called when the url is directly entered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm facing a serious issue related to Ember routes.

When I try to show a single item through a `link-to` helper, it works fine and hooks in route for `note.index` get called properly. But when I enter the URL (`localhost:4200/assessment/1/note/1`) directly in the browser, then route hooks are not called, either it is "model" hook or "setupController" hook or any other hook.
Basically I want to pass some extra parameters to my rails application with `store.find`.

Router.js

```
@resource "assessment", path: 'assessments/:assessment_id', ->
   @route 'edit'
   @resource "notes", ->
     @route "new"
@resource "note", path: "note/:note_id", ->
   @route 'edit'
```

note/index.js

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

noteIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: (params)->
        console.log('********************Model Hook******************')
        assessment = @modelFor('assessment')
        @store.find('note',params.note_id,assessment_id: assessment.get('id')});

    setupController: (controller,model)->
        @_super controller, model
        console.log('********************Setup Contr Hook********************')
        assessment = @modelFor('assessment')
        controller.set( "model",@store.find('note',model.id,assessment_id: assessment.get('id')});

`export default noteIndexRoute`
```

Note: I want to pass some extra parameters to my rails API, that's why I need to call hook on fetching item.

Comment: Which version are you on? The use of `this.resource` is not recommended at the moment.

Comment: I also don't see a `/assessment/1/note/1` route in your application, because `note` isn't nested under `assessment`.

Comment: Maybe not the specific problem you are having, but `controller.set(`model', ` is going to assign a promise to the `model` property, which is not what you probably want. You need to either do the set in a `then` clause, or more likely, do it in a `beforeModel` or `afterModel` hook where Ember will take care of resolving the promise for you. Also, don't you need a `return` in your `model` hook?

Comment: @torazaburo CoffeeScript (which from the code I assume is being used) has implicit return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember version is 1.10.0. Now route hooks are wroking when i enter url in browser and working well. actually my route file was index.js, which was present in `note/index.js` path. i move index.js route from note directory to `"app/routes/"` directory and change the name from index.js file to note.js file. so my new path for route file is `app/routes/note.js.` it resolved my issue and now my hooks are working properly and called when i enter direct url into broswer.

similarly i move and change the name and path of controller file and template file. from `note/index.js` and `note/index.hbs` to `app/routes/note.js` for controller and app/templates/note.hbs for template file.